# Можно сказать: оригинал повторён (автором)?

Tags: выбор-слов

> И пусть там давно уже копия. Оригинал исчез или похищен ещё при жизни
>   Караваджо и снова им повторён.

Comment: Оригинал повторить вряд ли возможно. Все повторяемое – копии, даже авторские.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*И пусть там давно уже копия. Оригинал исчез или похищен ещё при жизни Караваджо и **им же был повторён**.*

ВОСПРОИЗВЕСТИ, 2. **Повторить, воссоздать, восстановить** что-л. в точности. Правильно в. мелодию. В. в памяти чьи-л. слова. В. в фильме образ своего современника.

Пояснение

Наречие "заново" лучше опустить в любом случае. . "Воспроизвести" не подходит по стилю.

Answer (score 1):

Звучит сомнительно: скорее всего, это был *другой оригинал*. Неубедительно и выражение "снова повторить" (= повторить дважды), спокойнее "**заново воспроизведён**".